# Простая выборка из DB. Как правильно получать данные?

Tags: php

Есть 2 таблицы: одна с категориями, вторая с дочерними разделами.

Количество тех и других может увеличиваться до 1000.

**Задача:** вывести Категории в каждой из которых должны присутствовать её дочерние разделы.

Мой простой и в тоже время сомнительный вариант решения:

1. Вывод массива с ID всех категорий одним запросом. Далее через foreach создавать запросы к DB и выводить дочерние узлы принадлежащие этой категории.

Пример:

```
foreach ($category as $categoryId) {
        $childs = getChildsByCategoryId($categoryId); // метод возвращает  результат выборки из базы данных по parrentID
}
```

Этот вариант конечно же работает и я получаю все необходимое, но главной вопрос в том, на сколько это правильный подход. Меня смущает количество запросов к DB. На 100 категорий получается 100 запросов к бд.

Я относительно новичок в php, развейте мои сомнения или порекомендуйте наиболее верный вариант решения задачи, желательно с пояснением.

Comment: Одним запросом получаешь все пары Категория-Подкатегория, и потом на клиенте формируешь нужное отображение.

Comment: Подскажите, как может выглядеть такой запрос?

Answer (score 1):

Либо получайте сразу одним запросом данные и обработкой занимайтесь на клиенте, не загружая сервер БД или если у Вас всё же есть массив `id` категорий и надо получить именно так, используйте оператор `IN` в sql запросе, для получения информации один вызовом.

1. Приводите массив к строке (implode)
2. Соответственно не забудьте экранировать данные значения (привести к int и т.д. Если PDO используете, то подготовить запрос, чтобы не было инъекций)

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id IN (".implode(',',$category).")";
   ```

Comment: Вы представили вполне логичное решение, спасибо. Однако мне нужно связать вывод дочерних разделов с родительскими категориями, сохранив порядок. Например вот так:

Category1:
- child1
- child 2
- child 3
- ...


Category 2
- child 20
- child 24
- child 34
- ...

Ваш $sql будет содержать данные каждого раздела. Как быть дальше?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала получаем всё. Запросом типа:

```
SELECT category.name cat, subcategory.name sub
FROM category
LEFT JOIN subcategory ON category.id = subcategory.parent_id
ORDER BY category.name, subcategory.name
```

и на клиенте обрабатываем в цикле типа (очень схематично):

```
$cat="";
foreach ($record in $recordset) {
    if $record[cat] != $cat {echo $record[cat];}
    if ($record[sub]) {echo $record[sub];}
    $cat = $record[cat];
}
```